# How to calculate difference between all current date records total and previous dates records total using GROUP BY and INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join, difference

I have a table below:

```
SELECT * FROM reports;

 # id, date, o_type, quantity, vendor

'1', '2020-04-05', '2511', '200', 'apple'    
'2', '2020-04-05', '5120', '350', 'apple'    
'3', '2020-04-05', '2520', '150', 'apple'    
'4', '2020-04-05', '5114', '400', 'apple'    
'5', '2020-04-05', 'HG851', '200', 'google'    
'6', '2020-04-05', 'HG851A', '400', 'google'    
'7', '2020-04-05', 'MA5620G', '9000', 'google'    
'8', '2020-04-05', 'OT550', '7000', 'google'    
'9', '2020-04-05', 'OT925', '2000', 'google'    
'10', '2020-04-05', 'OT928', '2000', 'google'    
'11', '2020-04-06', '2520', '150', 'apple'    
'12', '2020-04-06', 'HG851', '200', 'google'    
'13', '2020-04-06', 'HG851', '200', 'google'    
'14', '2020-04-06', 'HG851A', '400', 'google'    
'15', '2020-04-07', '2511', '200', 'apple'    
'16', '2020-04-07', '5120', '350', 'apple'    
'17', '2020-04-07', '2520', '150', 'apple'    
'18', '2020-04-07', '5114', '400', 'apple'    
'19', '2020-04-07', 'G-440G-A', '200', 'NOKIA'    
'20', '2020-04-07', '1240GA', '400', 'NOKIA'    
'21', '2020-04-07', '1440GP', '9000', 'NOKIA'    
'22', '2020-04-07', 'B-0404G-B', '7000', 'NOKIA'    
'23', '2020-04-07', 'B2404GP', '2000', 'NOKIA'    
'24', '2020-04-07', 'G-881G-A', '2000', 'NOKIA'    
'25', '2020-04-08', 'G-881G-B', '150', 'NOKIA'    
'26', '2020-04-08', 'HG851', '200', 'google'    
'27', '2020-04-08', 'HG851A', '400', 'google'
```

I have a below query as per my project requirement:

```
SELECT Date(a.date), a.vendor, a.o_type, a.quantity, b.total FROM reports a 
INNER JOIN ( 
SELECT vendor, date, SUM(quantity) as total 
FROM reports WHERE date >= '2020-04-06' AND date <= '2020-04-08' 
GROUP BY vendor, date) b ON a.date = b.date AND a.vendor = b.vendor

 # Date(a.date), vendor, o_type, quantity, total

'2020-04-06', 'apple', '2520', '150', '150'    
'2020-04-06', 'google', 'HG851', '200', '800'    
'2020-04-06', 'google', 'HG851', '200', '800'    
'2020-04-06', 'google', 'HG851A', '400', '800'    
'2020-04-07', 'apple', '2511', '200', '1100'    
'2020-04-07', 'apple', '5120', '350', '1100'    
'2020-04-07', 'apple', '2520', '150', '1100'    
'2020-04-07', 'apple', '5114', '400', '1100'    
'2020-04-07', 'NOKIA', 'G-440G-A', '200', '20600'    
'2020-04-07', 'NOKIA', '1240GA', '400', '20600'    
'2020-04-07', 'NOKIA', '1440GP', '9000', '20600'    
'2020-04-07', 'NOKIA', 'B-0404G-B', '7000', '20600'    
'2020-04-07', 'NOKIA', 'B2404GP', '2000', '20600'    
'2020-04-07', 'NOKIA', 'G-881G-A', '2000', '20600'   
'2020-04-08', 'NOKIA', 'G-881G-B', '150', '150'    
'2020-04-08', 'google', 'HG851', '200', '600'    
'2020-04-08', 'google', 'HG851A', '400', '600'
```

I have to add an extra column DIFFERENCE to the above INNER JOIN query. How to calculate the difference between the current date and previous dates vendor column's total.

Example1:

```
2020-04-06 ---> apple ---> total(150)     
2020-04-07 ---> apple ---> total(1100) Here difference equals to -950 (150-1100)
```

Example2:

```
2020-04-07 ---> apple ---> total(1100)     
2020-04-08 ---> apple ---> total(0) Here difference equals to -1100 (0-1100)
```

Example3:

```
2020-04-07 ---> NOKIA ---> total(20600)     
2020-04-08 ---> apple ---> total(150) Here difference equals to -20450 (150-20600)
```

Please guide me on how to proceed further? or if any other details required from my end kindly let me know.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: My SQL version - 5.7.25